# Reverse for 'media' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

urls.py is

```
(r'^when/$', 'when'),
    (r'^media/$', 'media'),
    (r'^followup/$', 'followup'),
```

models.py

```
class Report(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=False)
    incident_number = models.CharField('Incident Number', max_length=100)
    device_id = models.CharField('Device Id', max_length=100)
    app_uuid = models.CharField('Unique App Id', max_length=100)
    created_date_time = models.DateTimeField('Created')
    manual_date_time = models.DateTimeField('Another time', null=True, blank=True)
    sent_date_time = models.DateTimeField('Sent')
```

views.py is

```
def when(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':

        reportform = ReportForm(data=request.POST)

        if reportform.is_valid():
            log.debug("test:%s",reportform)
            report = reportform.save(commit=False)
            report.user = request.user

            redirect_to = request.POST.get('next',
                reverse('media')
            )
            return HttpResponseRedirect(media)
        else:

            pass
    else:

        reportform = ReportForm()

    return render_to_response('incident/when.html',{
                  'newreport_menu': True, 
                  'form': reportform,
                   },
                   context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

I am getting the below error "

```
NoReverseMatch at /member/when/
Reverse for 'media' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found."
```

in the following line in views.py

```
redirect_to = request.POST.get('next',
                reverse('media')
            )
```

template is

```
<form action="/member/when/" method="POST"> {% csrf_token %}
                   {{ form.manual_date_time }} 
           <p id=ir-nextbutn><a href="{% url incident.views.media %}"> 
           {% include "buttons/next.html" %}</form>

AttributeError at /member/when/
'function' object has no attribute 'find'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to name your urls

```
url(r'^when/$', 'when', name='when'),
url(r'^media/$', 'media', name='media'),
url(r'^followup/$', 'followup', name='followup'),
```

Or to avoid conflicting url names you can prefix with your app's name.

```
url(r'^when/$', 'when', name='APP_NAME_when'),
url(r'^media/$', 'media', name='APP_NAME_media'),
url(r'^followup/$', 'followup', name='APP_NAME_followup'),
```

Obviously replace APP_NAME with the actual name of your app.

You can then update your template

```
{% url incident.views.media %}
# Changes to:
{% url 'media' %}
```

Comment: (r'^when/$', 'when', name='when'), it is giving error as invalid urls(syntax error)

Comment: getting this error"'function' object has no attribute 'find'"

Comment: Can you post your stack trace please.

Comment: That is just the error message.  The Stack trace will look like http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=upaiKK32.  From teh error page click "Switch to copy-and-paste view" and copy the bottom section.